# Does order of pip uninstall matter?

Tags: python, pip

If I have installed two python packages `a` and `b` using pip, is there any difference between

```
pip uninstall a
pip uninstall b
```

and

```
pip uninstall b
pip uninstall a
```

Does the order ever matter? Am I left in the same state in both cases?

Comment: You should be able to figure that out with a simple experiment, maybe with the `-v` argument.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't follow how I can answer that generically with an experiment. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which the uninstall are executed will not make any difference.

The [source code](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py) for `pip uninstall` shows how a list of files to be deleted is gathered before proceeding.

Note the two commands could be grouped as `pip uninstall a b` for convenience (or `pip uninstall b a` if you wish).